# What replacement part is needed to reattach the kitchen sink spray nozzle to its hose?

Tags: kitchens, faucet, sink, hose

The head of my sink's spray nozzle came off and I'm not sure what I need to fix it.
[image]

The end of the hose has just a removable hexagonal cap but really no way to attach to the nozzle as the hose doesn't have any threads.

[image: The end of the hose]
The end of the hose

[image: The base of the sprayer]
The base of the sprayer

I think there may have been a wad of duct tape jammed in there previously. I bought a new hose/nozzle but the other end of it wouldn't attach to the faucet/sprayer splitter under the sink, which uses an adapter that doesn't fit the new hose.

[image: Attachment under the sink with adapter]
Attachment under the sink with adapter

[image: Attachment under the sink without adapter]
Attachment under the sink without adapter

Unsure if I just need one replacement part, and what that part would be.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Your faucet manufacturer likely has information on this and perhaps replacement parts. It may be easier and perhaps cheaper to install a new faucet.

Comment: Those parts are usually made by machines, so repairing them yourself next to impossible.  You might be able to change the O-rings.  Will need a new assembly, hose and spray.

Comment: The "removable hexagonal cap" is a crimp collar. The reason it's now removable is that the part it was crimping in place is missing, or still in the sprayer head. I guess the 3rd picture probably is showing it still in the sprayer head, but it's unclear exactly what the picture is of from that angle. If it were in good repair it would **not** be removeable.

Comment: OK, the descriptions were buried in Alt-text, so I edited them in, and yes, the white bit in the center of the 3rd picture should be held into the end of the hose by the crimp collar. As you can see at the other end of the hose with the same sort of plastic insert, brass crimp fitting in the last picture.

Answer (score 2):

In the past, I've found internal cracks in similar chromed plastic head that precluded fixing it.

That said, the complete hose and spray assembly can be [found for US$10 and up](https://www.homedepot.com/s/kitchen%20sink%20sprayer%20and%20hose).

[BTW, one useful DIY hack is to connect the new hose assembly to the existing hose under the sink, if it is difficult to attach the new hose directly to the fitting under the faucet. Simply cut the ends of both hoses to reasonable length, insert appropriate size stub of PVC or copper pipe in the ends, and fasten with two hose clamps.]

Comment: Nope. Model# RP60097SS is $45, and I'm not even sure it fits. Might as well get a new faucet.

Comment: See the note about using almost *any* replacement, even the US$10, and simply splicing the hoses together, if needed. Most replacements also come with their own escutcheon, easy to replace, as well.